# Feedback for self-signed certificates setup for custom product auth?

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, certificates, x.509

```
HW (linux) <---Eth---> Official PC (win,mac,linux)
               |
               |
                ----> Man-in-the-middle eavesdrop
```

I'm looking to prevent an unauthorized party inside the LAN to make sense of communications between an official PC and a custom piece of HW.

The custom protocol used to communicate works on top of TCP. It can be assumed the unauth party won't have access to the filesystem of the official PC.

My current design involves using self-signed client certificates that we'd use in the official PC. Self-signed server certificates would be present inside the custom HW. The software would wrap the current socket comms in TLS, via libtls.

The certificates would be generated once with the openssl command and last for a couple of years.

Does this look reasonable or is it junk? Any gotchas?

**EDIT**

Commenting on some of the points in Steffen Ullrich's answer:

The client and server certificates would only be used to connect from specific official PCs to the device, and not for any other kind of communication to other devices or software. The distribution of the client certificate is controlled. The server certificate details can be made known to the official PCs, and the client certificate details can be made known to the custom HW.

- 1st point: In the client, we can validate the server certificate using its fingerprint. In the server, we can validate the client certificate using its fingerprint too, if needed.
- 2nd point: The distribution of the client certificate is strictly controlled, so nobody outside of the official PCs should have it. IIUC, that means other connections without the client certificate would be rejected (right? Otherwise, would it help to invert client/server?)
- 3rd point: We can update client/server certificates (both or just one of the two) as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of TLS makes sense. The use of self-signed certificates makes sense as long as you properly deal with the servers certificate at the client side. This means that

- The trusted self-signed certificate properly validated for example by using the fingerprint (pinning) or the certificate itself. This means also that it is known before the first connection is established by the client, so that already the first connection can be validated.
- The trusted self-signed certificate is only trusted for connections to the specific device. This means especially that it is not imported as a generally trusted CA into the browser. Otherwise it could be used to intercept other connections in case the private key of this certificate somehow gets known to the attacker.
- A working process is established how trust into the certificate can be revoked in case it gets compromised and how it can be replaced when it expires or gets revoked.

Your question does not provide enough detail to decide if these requirements are satisfied by your design.

Comment: For the first point, what do you mean by "validated"? Not sure I fully follow the point made and its implications, but yes, the server and client can both be made aware of each other certificates before the first connect. ///// For 2nd point, what kind of other connections could be intercepted? Do you mean a browser accessing the HW device?

Comment: @ArthurChamz: Validation means that the certificate is the expected one. For CA issued certificates this usually means checking expiration, subject, status revocation and that it was issued by a trusted CA. For self-signed certificates it can for example checked against the expected fingerprint.

Comment: *" For 2nd point, what kind of other connections could be intercepted?"* - TLS connections from any system/software which trusts this certificate as trusted CA can be MITM. This is not restricted to connections accessing the HW.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, please see my edit with more info on each point.

Comment: @ArthurChamz: If  the self-signed server certificate is also a CA certificate (typical case since otherwise openssl would ignore it when put in the CA store) and if it is put into the browsers (or other applications or systems) trust store as trusted CA (also common setup or misconfiguration) and if an attacker might get hand on this certificates private key (whatever *"strictly controlled"* really prevents in practice), then this certificate might be used as the trusted issuer inside MITM attacks since it can be used to issue certificates for arbitrary sites and is trusted by the the client.

Comment: Thanks again! I hope I'm understanding this right: If the official PC filesystem is compromised, an attacker could obtain keys/certs easily. There are no further access controls in place, so I'm not sure it matters much if the self-signed server cert is also a CA certificate. If the attacker's got it, it would be too late (the data sent across is always the same for particular transactions, there's rarely any valuable user input). Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @ArthurChamz: the problem is more the certificate and key on the HW since this is the server certificate. And it matters a lot if it is a CA certificate or not since only CA certificates can be used to issue new certificates: an attacker could use this for example use it to issue a certificate for google.com and if the browser on the PC trusts the HWs server certificate as CA then connections to google.com could be MITM.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: How could using a CA certificate be abused to issue other certificates – only the public CA certificate is distributed, and without the private key it cannot be used to sign other certificates?

Comment: @not2savvy: there is a difference between the intended distribution and a compromise of the certificate. I'm talking about the latter one, i.e. about the impact when  the private key gets known to an attacker. By restricting what an attacker can use this certificate for one can limit the impact.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, so you are not talking about compromising the client, but the computer that holds the private keys, right? This computer has the private key of the root CA anyway, or there is another one that has it. So I still don’t see the difference?

Comment: @not2savvy: I'm talking about compromising the computer (the HW) which has the private key of the CA and then using this knowledge to MITM connection from the computer (client) which trusts this CA to arbitrary systems like google.com.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Understood. Yet, my point is that there must be a computer holding the private key of the root CA somewhere, independent from what type of certificate I use on the client. If we are speaking of compromising that computer, what certificate is on the client doesn’t make a difference risk-wise.

Comment: @not2savvy: That's what I'm saying: *"...in case the private key of this certificate somehow gets known to the attacker."*. If you can make 100% sure that the attacker never gets access to the private key or that you'll detect this and mitigate before the private key will be misused then you don't have to worry about this risk. Otherwise it would be wise to make sure that the security impact will be low if this ever happens.